# TypeError for wrong number of arguments when correct number is given

Tags: python, delegates, typeerror

Python's native exceptions are driving me insane.

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          rtn = None
          if len(args) < self.positionals:
               raise TypeError(f"Expected {self.positionals} positional arguments, received {len(args)}")
          for kwarg in kwargs.keys():
               if not kwarg in self.names:
                    raise TypeError(f"Unexpected Keyword Argument :'{kwarg}'")  
          print(f"invoking with {args} {kwargs}")
          print(len(args))
          print(len(kwargs))
          for invocation in self.invocationList:
               rtn = invocation(*args, **kwargs)
          return rtn
```

I am getting a TypeError when invoking the captured delegate, `TypeError: ProcessMeta() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` when I absolutely know for a fact that only one is being passed. I checked, the console tells me the argumetns

```
invoking with (<exwrtcutil.StructuredMessage object at 0x7f29a0287b20>,) {}
1
0
```

TypeError doesn't give me a way to see what arguments its invoking with so I can track them down. I'm completely up the wall here. I don't know what I could do to be more convinced that I am only passing a single argument, when I call the code from `self.onMetaReceive(_message)`

This issue doesn't occur with other functions that consume the exact same objects, and it goes away if I wrap ProcessMeta in a delegate, and then place that delegate inside  the delegate onMetaReceived and everything is gravy. Which is honestly fine I guess, but completely baffling. The only difference I can perceive is that ProcessMeta is a class method

Comment: Apparently adding the @staticmethod decorator to the class functions fixes it, but it should have to because I didnt tell python they were instance methods, and they don't expect or accept a self argument and they are referenced from ClassName.ProcessContent no instance.ProcessContent so literally no reason ever for them to get that wrong. Great language, still don't know what was broken but I guess its fixed